# Covering a grid with minimal number of rectangles

Tags: algorithms, language-agnostic

Input data: a grid of cells of different colors.
Problem: how do I cover this grid with a minimal number of non-overlapping rectangles so each rectangle contains the cells of one color only?

[image]

Comment: @Erik Eidt, a good-enough solution achievable in short time would work as well.

Comment: Your picture implies the colored areas of each color will always have the shape of rectangles already, as in your example? Then it is trivial, each color already represents the recangle you are looking for.

Comment: @Doc Brown, however, some of these rectangles can have size 1x1 cell ;)

Comment: You missed my point, read my comment again. I guess you example is not a representative one, you want the problem to be solved for more complex situations, right?

Comment: @Doc Brown, well, I can't represent all possible scenarios. Rectangles can be of any size - that's it.

Comment: But I guess you won't just it to be solved for trivial scenarios like the one you showed us above?

Comment: @Tulains Córdova, well the simplest solution would be a greedy selection algorightm. I hoped someone has better ideas.

Comment: The problem needs to be solved for each color indivually. Each area of one color forms a rectilinear polygon which has to be dissected into rectangles. And this question was already asked and anwered on stackoverflow in 2011: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919298/algorithm-for-finding-the-fewest-rectangles-to-cover-a-set-of-rectangles But beware, this is not a trivial problem, surely more complicated than your image imposes.

Comment: User626528 [edit] all your comment answers into your question so that it clearly describes your scenario(s).

Comment: @JanDoggen: why should he? The link I gave contains an exhaustive answer on stackoverflow to his problem (don't know, however, if the OP understood that, since he did not react). No need to repeat that answer here again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639154/algorithm-to-find-the-minimum-number-of-rectangles-covering-certain-elements-in